# Retrieving parent nodes of a specified empty child node

Tags: xml, xpath, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to use XPATH to return the parent node of child node in XML that contains no content within a PL/SQL procedure.

So far, I have the following XMLextract that will return the wrapper parent of a child node that has an id of either 10 or 11 where p_xml_content is my xml document.

```
   xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//return/issueEventType[id=11] /../. | //return/issueEventType[id=10] /../.')
```

I need to convert this statement to return all return tags that contain an empty completionDate node.

I thought along the lines of this but not sure whether this will work:

```
   xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//return[completionDate=''] /../.')
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Jezzipin

Comment: Please give us a sample XML in order to give you the XPath espression. Maybe what you need is //return//*[completionDate='']/.. but to be sure we need the XML structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that "empty completionDate node" means "a completionDate element with no child node", that would translate to `completionDate[not(node())]`

And "all return tags that contain an empty completionDate node" therefore translates to

```
//return[completionDate[not(node())]]
```

So try:

```
xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//return[completionDate[not(node())]]')
```

Your expression, slightly modified, `//return[completionDate=""]` also works.

With the following sample XML

```
<sample>
    <return id="1">
        <completionDate></completionDate>
        <otherData>some data</otherData>
    </return>
    <return id="2">
        <completionDate>2013-09-10</completionDate>
    </return>
    <return id="3">
        <completionDate />
        <otherDataAlt>more data</otherDataAlt>
    </return>
    <return id="4">
        <completionDate>2013-09-11</completionDate>
        <otherDataAlt>alt data</otherDataAlt>
    </return>
    <return id="5">
        <completionDate></completionDate>
    </return>
    <return id="6">
        <completionDate />
    </return>
</sample>
```

both `//return[completionDate=""]` and `//return[completionDate[not(node())]]` return `<return>` nodes with IDs 1, 3, 5 and 6. (tested on http://www.xpathtester.com/ and http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Comment: I edited my answer with explanation but I could be wrong on "empty child node"  understanding

Comment: This assumption is incorrect as nodes can contain content as well as additional nodes. My completionDate nodes never have any children, just content such as <completionDate>Date Here</completionDate>. I wish to return the parent node return when these tags are empty e.g. <completionDate></completionDate>

Comment: `completionDate[not(node())]` perdicate works for `<completionDate></completionDate>`. And `//return[completionDate='']` should also work as the complete expession in your case. I tried with some  XML with `<return><completionDate></completionDate></return><return><completionDate>some text</completionDate></return><return><completionDate /></return>` and both expression return the 2 empty nodes, either with `= ''` or `[not(node())]` predicate. If you post sample XML content as @BillVelasquez asked, I could confirm or infirm

Comment: Or do you mean `<completionDate>` nodes are not always "direct" children nodes of `<return>`? If they are, `[not(node())]` applies only to `<completionDate>` so it's OK